# How to get site url source code with aspx code?

Tags: asp.net

How to get site URL source from aspx code?

The code below belongs to the PHP language. How can we make code like this for the Aspx language?

`<?php $php = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"); echo $php; ?>`
How can we get the source code of a site for aspx language?

it is php other code aspx how come aspx code ?

Comment: You cannot access the source code of a page that is processed on the server-side by any means.

Comment: You can get the raw aspx page. So, it not clear if the user means the source to the aspx page, or the source of the aspx page AND ALSO the server code behind? (they are two concepts in asp.net).  My answer here shows how to read and send the raw aspx source page to the client side.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will read the raw source .aspx page, and send it to the browser.

So, the markup for this page is:

```
<h3>Enter aspx page to read</h3>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="cmdView"
    runat="server"
    Text="Go"
    Style="margin-left: 30px"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdView_Click" />


<h3>Result</h3>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
    Width="50%" Height="600" Style="background-color: black; color: white">
</asp:TextBox>
```

The code for the button click is:

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sRawFile As String = Server.MapPath(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim sRawAspx As String = File.ReadAllText(sRawFile)

    TextBox2.Text = sRawAspx

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: warning - this introduces a huge security vulnerability

Comment: the question as asked to read raw souce .aspx pages is of its nature a security issue, and the fact that this is possible does not suggest, hint nor imply this is a good idea. The warming goes against the person asking the question - not the answer. Unless you suggesting there is a "secure" way to answer this question? So yes, without question, such a page and code would not be and should not EVER be exposed to public users and a non secured page (so, yes, this page at the VERY min needs security roles, and not public roles -- eg: say for role=SiteAdmin).